# Auto Delete Old Wordpress Posts in Certain Categories via SQL

Tags: sql, wordpress, categories, posts

I found the following SQL script here in another thread:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_type` = 'post'
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > 120
```

This script will find and delete all posts older than 120 days.
However, I'm wondering if this can also be done in certain categories only.
I'd like to keep all the old posts in some categories, but delete all old posts in others.

Also, if so, is there a way to make this script run every day?

I'm extremely green when it comes to this sort of thing, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use wp_delete_post ( http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_post )  function to do what you wanna do, because there a lot of relationships beetween posts comments etc. in the database. => http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png

To run this script everyday you have to make a CRON job on your server :
http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply.


All the posts I intend to delete are without comments, and are aggregated.

You still mean I should look into what you posted here regardless?

Comment: It should be said that I'm talking about several thousand posts.
I may even be up to 100 000 posts... :/

Comment: Don't mind about the amount of posts, you get the list of post concerned by using a custom SQL query like you've written before and use the result with wp_delete_post($id).

In your script you just have to do this:
Request the SQL result / 
Store the result in array / 
Foreach result in array wp_delete_post($id)

Comment: Any chance you could show me how, where and what to do? I didn't write what I posted, I just found it. All I know is where to run that, and that's about it, I'm afraid. Like I said, I'm extremely green in this area, and I frankly have no clue where to even begin.